# Container Won't Contain Everything

Tags: html, css, containers

I cannot get my `.container{}` to encompass all the content on my web page. My lower navigation buttons are sitting outside the container (marked by a 1px black border) and I can't figure out why. I'm not sure where I've went wrong in my CSS or HTML code! Thanks in advance for your help. Here is a link to my CodePen: https://codepen.io/IDCoder/pen/rGWeEE?editors=0100

Here are my code snippets:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Ms.Jane Equities Management Corp</title>
  </head>  
      <body> 
        <div class="container-fluid">

          <!-- Top Box -->
          <div class="wrap">           
            <div class="Logos">
              <img src="https://s26.postimg.org/iqkxecqnd/Coldwell_Banker-_Logo_RS1.jpg" width="150" height="82"/>
              <img src="https://s26.postimg.org/iqkxecqnd/Coldwell_Banker-_Logo_RS1.jpg" width="150" height="82"/>                     </div>      
            <div class ="nav wrap">  
            <!--navigation buttons-->                      
                  <ul class="navigation">
                    <li id="NAV-ONE"><a href="#">LOG IN</a></li>
                    <li id="NAV-TWO"><a href="#">BUY A HOME</a></li>
                    <li id="NAV-THREE"><a href="#">SELL A HOME</a></li>
                    <li id="NAV-FOUR"><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
                 </ul>           
            </div>
         </div>

          <!-- Middle Box -->
          <div class="row two">
            <div>
              <div class="floater box">
                <!--<div class="search box wrap">
                <div class="search">
      <input type="text" class="searchTerm" placeholder="What are you looking for?">
      <button type="submit" class="searchButton">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
     </button>

              </div>
              </div>-->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

          <!-- Bottom Box -->
          <div class="row three">
            <div class ="nav wrap 2">  
              <!--navigation buttons-->                      
                    <ul class="navigation">
                      <li id="NAV-A"><a href="#">MY LISTINGS</a></li>
                      <li id="NAV-B"><a href="#">COMMUNITIES SERVED</a></li>
                      <li id="NAV-C"><a href="#">PROPERTIES</a></li>
                    </ul>    
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
      </body>
<html>
```

CSS:

```
.container-fluid{
border: 1px solid #000000;
max-width: 1600px;
/*overflow: hidden;*/
}

.wrap{
background-color: yellow;
display: inline: flex;
/*overflow: hidden;*/
}


.Logos{
  width: 55%;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: blue;

}


.nav.wrap{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: green;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 25px;
}


 ul.navigation{
 font: bold 11px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

 /*text-align center;*/
 /*border: 1px solid green;*/
 /*overflow: hidden;*/  
}


.navigation li {
  display: inline-block;

}

.navigation a {
  background: #395870;
  background: linear-gradient(#49708f, #293f50);
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.navigation a:hover {
  background: #314b0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
.navigation li:first-child a {
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}
.navigation li:last-child a {
  border-right: 0;
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
}



.row.two{
background-image: url(https://s1.postimg.org/5gvbly4hin/East_Hyde_Park_Chicago_aerial_0470.jpg);
    background-position: absolute;
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    max-width: 1600px;
  height: 550px;
        margin: auto;  
}

 .floater.box{
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    opacity: .45;
    max-width: 75%;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}

/*.search {
  width: 50%;
  position: relative
}

.searchTerm {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid #00B4CC;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
  color: #9DBFAF;
}

.searchTerm:focus{
  color: #00B4CC;
}

.searchButton {
  position: absolute;  
  right: -50px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 36px;
  border: 1px solid #00B4CC;
  background: #00B4CC;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.search.box.wrap{
  width: 30%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
*/
```

Comment: So what exactly is the issue? You want the .container-fluid to take up the whole page, or where exactly is .container?

Answer (score 3):

I think your `div.nav.wrap` is getting pushed down because it's floated and there's no room for it in the container and because it's floated the container doesn't adjust for it. If you remove the float, you'll see the container start to contain it. That's normal float behaviour - elements with float are out of the 'flow' of the document so other elements aren't affected by them.

I'd just add a negative top margin to push it back up. I'd usually do this in rem or depending on how you size the nav height. So your existing `.nav.wrap` rule would become:

```
.nav.wrap{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
  float: right;
  margin-top: -35px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I made it work by taking out float: right....this is my current code : 
.nav.wrap.two{
  display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;    
}